# pseudo :before outside of div

Tags: css

I've wrote this CSS :

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height:150px;
  margin-left:150px;
  background: lightblue;
}

div::before {
  content:'';
  width:50px;
  height:150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background:red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia rem quasi laborum dolor explicabo nobis pariatur ad deleniti repellendus dicta, ducimus expedita! Temporibus quo facilis quae magni, saepe, sapiente rem.</p>
</div>
```

What I want is to put the `:before` content outside div but still collapse to it and not inside.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `transform: translateX(-100%)` with `left: 0` and add `position: relative` on parent

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}
div::before {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia rem quasi laborum dolor explicabo nobis pariatur ad deleniti repellendus dicta, ducimus expedita! Temporibus quo facilis quae magni, saepe, sapiente rem.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Great that's exactly what I want, I did not think about that one. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options, I would use the transform property which only requires a single style entry.

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height:150px;
  margin-left:150px;
  background: lightblue;
}

div::before {
  content:'';
  width:50px;
  height:150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background:red;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia rem quasi laborum dolor explicabo nobis pariatur ad deleniti repellendus dicta, ducimus expedita! Temporibus quo facilis quae magni, saepe, sapiente rem.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with left property of the :before and setting div to position relative

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height:150px;
  margin-left:150px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  left: -50px;
  content:'';
  width:50px;
  height:150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background:red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia rem quasi laborum dolor explicabo nobis pariatur ad deleniti repellendus dicta, ducimus expedita! Temporibus quo facilis quae magni, saepe, sapiente rem.</p>
</div>
```